# How to remove line breaks on code formatting in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, format

How to make intellij remove line breaks from this

```
long orderId =
                orderInserter
                        .executeAndReturnKey(values)
                        .longValue();
```

to become this:

```
long orderId = orderInserter.executeAndReturnKey(values).longValue();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just found the answer. it's: `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wraping and Braces` Uncheck Line Breaks.
[image]